# Galleria Classic onclick thumbnail open in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

[image]

1) On click Thumbnails Open this image in lightbox

or

2)on click thumbnail at that time slide image i want after slide image then display in lightbox.

[Site Url](http://www.californiadog.com/v-style-mesh-harness-for-small-dogs-grey-black.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This was fixed using extend function see the code hear.

[Full Script code hear](http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/galleria-classic-onclick-thumbnail-open-in-lightbox/)

[Apply on this demo site](http://www.yourbusinessassistant.com.au/magento/index.php/harley-davidson/sportster-parts/2-dual-handlebar-clamp-assemblies.html)

```
    var flag = false;

//codex

     extend: function(){
                this.bind('image', function(e) {
                       if(flag == true){
                           this.openLightbox(this.getIndex());
                       }else{
                          flag = true;
                     }
                });         
            }
```